Linux Disk Not Detected After Formatting Unless Windows Partition Is Present
I recently formatted my disk to use only Linux, but I’m facing an issue where my system doesn’t detect the disk unless I add a Windows partition. I want to use only Linux on my system and do not want to dual-boot with Windows. However, it seems like I am "obligated" to have a Windows partition for my disk to be recognized and boot correctly.
details btw: my laptop don't support legacy mode (i3 10th gen) The system only detects the disk if I add a Windows partition. Without it, Linux won’t boot or detect the disk.
I searched extensively on YouTube and Google for a solution, but the only fix I found was to enable legacy mode, which my laptop does not support (it's UEFI-only). I’m hoping there’s another method to resolve this without needing a Windows partition.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you explain exactly what you did, how you did it, and what kind of Linux you installed? You can run linux with both legacy and/or uefi.

Have you try to disable "secure boot" in the UEFI/BIOS settings? And check your boot order.

Sounds like a firmware issue to me, especially if the "factory default configuration" of the laptop included a recovery partition. Does the windows partition need to be any particular size? If it only needs to exist, you certainly can make a tiny fake "Windows partition" to make the firmware happy, Also, make sure you're using GPT partitioning if your system does not support legacy mode, as I'd expect a UEFI-only system to very likely have bugs in firmware-level MBR partitioning support.

hello @Z0OM  , I have a disk with a dual-boot setup: Kali Linux on one partition and Windows on another. The problem is, when I try to use only Kali Linux for the entire disk , the system won't detect the disk, and I get the "Operating System Not Found" error when I try to boot my laptop , my laptop doesn't support legacy  , yes the secure boot is desable
